# Improving performance of sliding window summation of a matrix

Tags: matlab

This is a follow-up question to this post:

[Sliding window summation of a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63055349/sliding-window-summation-of-a-matrix)

I have a 50x50 matrix, and I'd like to sum up the values in every 10x10 (or another set size value - always square) overlapping grid i.e.:

[image]

Overlapping windows are shown only in the diagonal for the sake of clarity. I'd then like to define a particular coordinate (index) in the matrix e.g. `m(23,3)` and get a list of all windows this coordinate is contained within.

My attempt to solve this problem is as follows:

```
x = rand(50,50);
result = conv2(x, ones(10), 'valid'); %calculate the sum for each overlapping 10 x 10 window
tmp = zeros(50,50);
tmp(23,3) = 1; %location of a person, in this case - 23,3
result2 = conv2(tmp, ones(10), 'valid'); 
xx = find(result2); %get all non-zero values i.e. the windows the person falls into
```

I then also want to detect situations where any window the person is a part of, also has a sum above a certain value e.g.:

```
if sum(result(xx)>55)>0
   #do something
end
```

It works - but I need to call this as part of a function, and it has to run a huge number of times. It is not the most efficient method of doing this i'm sure - and it is currently adding unacceptable levels of runtime to my script.

Can anybody show me the most efficient way of doing this? Perhaps the windows the person falls into does not have to be explicitly detected but can be calculated mathematically? At the end of the day, all I want to know is if a given person at a specific coordinate is part of a window that also contains a value above X.

Comment: So, use `xx = find(result2 & result>55)?` That will give `xx` (linear index) according to the two conditions

Answer (score 1):

We start with:

```matlab
w = 10;           % size of square window
x = rand(50,50);  % original image
result = conv2(x, ones(w), 'valid');
                  % sum for each overlapping w x w window
```

Note that `result(1,1)` contains the sum for the window `x(1:w,1:w)`.

Given the coordinates `p=[23,3]` in the original image `x`, the set of windows that contain this coordinate are the ones at `result(p(1)-(0:9),p(2)-(0:9))`, but excluding the out-of-bound indices. Excluding these is as follows:

```matlab
i = p(1)-(0:9);
j = p(2)-(0:9);
i(i<1 | i>size(result,1)) = [];
j(j<1 | j>size(result,2)) = [];
```

If you want to see if any of those windows is above a certain value, do

```matlab
if any(result(i,j)>55)
   % do something
end
```